# ESP32 WebSocketsServer - stream pots data to web browser

Tags: esp32

I would like to stream pots data to a web browser using websockets.  I'm using WebSocketsServer on a Huzzah but sendTXT isn't working, but does for Connected WStype.  Is there a way to do this?   Partial code:

```
  // New client has connected
case WStype_CONNECTED:
{
  IPAddress ip = webSocket.remoteIP(client_num);
  Serial.printf("[%u] Connection from client: ", client_num);
  Serial.println(ip.toString());
  webSocket.sendTXT(client_num, "Server says Client is connected \r\n");
}

void loop() {
int potValue =analogRead(A4);
//Serial.println(potValue);
webSocket.loop();
}
```

javascript:

```
/*----  WEBSOCKET SERVER CONNECTION    ------- --*/
connect();

function connect()
{

var socket = new WebSocket("ws://10.0.0.1:1337");

try
{
    message('<p class="event">Socket Status: '+socket.readyState);

    socket.onopen = function()
    {
    message('<p class="event">Socket open Status: '+socket.readyState+' (open)');
    }
    socket.onmessage = function(msg)
    {
     message('<p class="message">Received: '+msg.data);
    }
    socket.onclose = function()
    {
    message('<p class="event">Socket close Status: '+socket.readyState+' (Closed)');
    }           
} 
catch(exception)
{
    message('<p>Error'+exception);
}


/* ----SEND TO SERVER -----*/


$('.fan').click(function()
{
    var idClicked = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(idClicked);

    sendTo(idClicked);

});


function sendTo(idClicked)
{
    socket.send(idClicked);
    message('<p class="event">Sent: '+idClicked)
}

function message(msg)
{
    $('#pots').html(msg+'</p>');
}
```

Comment: please show the non-working code

Comment: how do you send the text?

Comment: do you have a java script web socket client in a page running in browser?